# Not able to remove breakpoint in chrome dev tools - Nodejs Debugging

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, chrome-debugging

I'm debugging nodejs application using chrome dev tools. I can create breakpoint using single click while application is in debugging mode. However I have to right click and remove the breakpoint. I can't remove the breakpoint by single click again. Or I have to remove it from breakpoints list on the right side. Application is started using `node --inspect-brk server.js` command in case if that matters.

Google Chrome version -> 83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) (64-bit)
node version -> v9.11.2
npm version -> 6.14.5
macOS Catalina -> 10.15.4